# Configure Emacs to Respect Windows File Attributes?

Tags: microsoft-windows, completion, find-file, filenames, system-environment

Is it possible to configure Emacs under Windows to respect the 'hidden' and 'system' NTFS file attributes for example by filtering out these files during selection of filename completion candidates in the minibuffer in order to unclutter the interface?

The command

```
(shell-command-to-string "attrib c:\\foo.txt")
```

produces a string where the letters H and S at the beginning denote 'hidden' and 'system' respectively.

Ideally, there would exist a variable somewhere in emacs that would globally determine whether or not these files are 'seen' by emacs.  Does this feature already exist for win32 users?

(Note that in linux, the notion of a hidden file is a simple matter of whether or not the filename or directory name starts with a period. Dired already supports toggling the display of these files and directories by using the period shortcut.)